# Concat string to variable in HTML conditional class? Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am creating a dynamic list and trying to apply a class to the list element if it meets a specific condition.

```
<li *ngFor="let starNumber of numbersOfStars" [class.filled]="'intro' + starNumber  >= starNumber" ></li>
```

As you can see I am trying to concat the string "intro" to the array value.

Just for reference, "numberOfStars" is an array:

```
public numberOfStars: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Also, I hard-coded a value for variable that is being created. I expect the first variable to check is "intro1":

```
public intro1: number = 1;
```

This does not work. Am I concatenating the string and variable correctly? Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't understand your syntax. Which css class would you like to apply, and when? Because your current code is equivalent to `[class.filled]="false"`. How could the string 'intro2' could be >= 2?

Comment: The first list element would be 'intro1' >= 1. In the .ts file I set the value of intro1 to 1. So it should evaluate to true.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to compare the string 'intro1' to the number 1. JavaScript of course allows that, but the result is false.

Comment: I am trying to create a new variable that will bind to a public variable in the .ts file.

Comment: 'intro1' is not a variable. I's a string. I *guess* you should store your intro values in an array, and use intro[starNumber].

Comment: That is a good idea. I did something similar, but instead am using an object to make this work. Thank you for your time. I realize now that I was trying to evaluate a string against a number. I thought I would be able to create a variable instead of string.